# How to group array of objects by value of object and sum the result in new property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this

```
const orders = [{
    "oreder": "Order/1",
    "itemCount": 2    
  }, {
    "oreder": "Order/2",
    "itemCount": 1
  }, {
    "oreder": "Order/3",
    "itemCount": 3
  }, {
    "oreder": "Order/4",
    "itemCount": 2
  }, {
    "oreder": "Order/5",
    "itemCount": 2
  }, {
    "oreder": "Order/6",
    "itemCount": 1
 }];
```

and what I'm trying to achieve is to group objects by `itemCount` and ad new property to each object with the name `numberOfOrders` and value which would be the sum of the same `itemCount` properties. Here's an example of what I want

```
const orders = [{
    "itemCount": 1,
    "numberOfOrders": 2,
  }, {
    "itemCount": 2,
    "numberOfOrders": 3,
  }, {
    "itemCount": 3,
    "numberOfOrders": 1,
 }];
```

I've tried to achieve this by using reduce

```
const result = orders.reduce(function (r, a) {
   r[a.itemCount] = r[a.itemCount] || [];
   r[a.itemCount].push(a);
   return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

but this is not what I want. How can I do this? Any example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count instead of collecting items in an array. At the end take the value form the object.

```js
const
    orders = [{ order: "Order/1", itemCount: 2 }, { order: "Order/2", itemCount: 1 }, { order: "Order/3", itemCount: 3 }, { order: "Order/4", itemCount: 2 }, { order: "Order/5", itemCount: 2 }, { order: "Order/6", itemCount: 1}],
    result = Object.values(orders.reduce(function(r, { itemCount }) {
        r[itemCount] = r[itemCount] || { itemCount, numberOfOrders: 0 };
        r[itemCount].numberOfOrders++;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This way is totally good, but I wonder how to achieve the same thing if the object key is string. F.e. "itemCount"

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted? (keys of object are strings unless it is a symbol.)

Comment: orders = [{ "Transactions.orderId": "Order/1", "Transactions.itemCount": "24"}, {"Transactions.orderId": "Order/2", "Transactions.itemCount": "3"}].... something like this

Comment: i see .. hopefully. you may need a different destructuring: `function(r, { 'Transactions.itemCount': itemCount }) {` and then you need a property for the result set.

Comment: That's it! Awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array reduce** method to count the frequency of itemCount. After that use **Object.keys** to get all the keys and use **array map** method to create a new object.

```js
const orders = [
  {
    oreder: 'Order/1',
    itemCount: 2,
  },
  {
    oreder: 'Order/2',
    itemCount: 1,
  },
  {
    oreder: 'Order/3',
    itemCount: 3,
  },
  {
    oreder: 'Order/4',
    itemCount: 2,
  },
  {
    oreder: 'Order/5',
    itemCount: 2,
  },
  {
    oreder: 'Order/6',
    itemCount: 1,
  },
];

let ret = orders.reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  const key = c.itemCount;
  if (!p[key]) p[key] = 1;
  else p[key] += 1;
  return p;
}, {});

ret = Object.keys(ret).map((x) => ({
  itemCount: x,
  numberOfOrders: ret[x],
}));

console.log(ret);
```